# css for permanent change on mouseover

Tags: css, hover

It's easy to swap two elements on hover, with use of the `visibility: hidden` and `:hover`.  However, I want the second state, with the replaced element, to persist even when the mouse leaves the element.  This would be easy to do with JavaScript, but is there a way to do it in pure CSS?

Answer (score 2):

CSS is stateless, so no there is no way to change the state in a permanent way. The only way I  can think of to come close, is to increase the size of the element (or have a sub-element that is big) so that the mouse does not leave, but it would obscure the rest of the page and controls.